# Magento 2: Upload PDF gives Unsupported image format. Error

Tags: magento2, custom, pdf, upload, magento2.1.6

I'm able to upload from Backend TinyMCE Editor.

But when it upload it gives "Unsupported image format." Error.

I need to overwrite that function but it's private.

Below is code what I have tried

**magento\app\code\Custom\Cms\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2" type="Custom\Cms\Gd2" />
    <type name="Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="resizeParameters" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="height" xsi:type="number">75</item>
                <item name="width" xsi:type="number">100</item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="extensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="pdf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
                <item name="image_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="jpg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="png" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="gif" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="pdf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
                <item name="media_allowed" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="flv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="swf" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="avi" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="mov" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="rm" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="wmv" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <argument name="dirs" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="exclude" xsi:type="string"/>
                <item name="include" xsi:type="string"/>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**magento\app\code\Custom\Cms\Gd2.php**

```
namespace Custom\Cms;

class Gd2 extends \Magento\Framework\Image\Adapter\Gd2
{
    private function _getCallback($callbackType, $fileType = null, $unsupportedText = 'Unsupported image format.')
    {
    }
}
```